# Automatically redirect from Announcement?

Tags: redirect

I have set up a news ticker on the front page of my intranet.  The ticker draws its headlines from an Announcements list, which contains items that link to some handpicked pages from the News section of the intranet.

What I would like to happen is for the user to click on a news ticker headline and to seamlessly be redirected to a relevant news page, rather than be taken to the announcement itself and have to manual click a link in it to get to the relevant page.

Is this something that can be done?  Or is there a better option than trying to set this up using the Announcement list?

Cheers,

Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column to the announcements list of type Hyperlink. Use this column to point to the relevant news page. Then, in your news ticker display, show the Hyperlink column instead of the title.

Comment: Thanks Paul!  That sounds like a pretty elegant solution. :-)